# powershell arrays add-member - looking for elegant code

Tags: arrays, powershell, pipeline

I have a pretty basic PowerShell array: $TestArray with 2 text columns: Price and TimeStamp (that's the way I get them, nothing to be done about this):

```
Price  TimeStamp       
-----  ----------------       
0.0567 1542056680.72746
0.0567 1542056650.34414
0.0555 1542056197.46668
0.0551 1542056167.28967
```

I would like, **in a single PowerShell line** to add a rounded `Time2` value

```
$Time2 = [math]::Round($TestArray.TimeStamp)
```

The code I am thinking of is:

```
 $TestArray | Add-Member -Name Time2 -MemberType NoteProperty -Value { [math]::Round($Table.TimeStamp) }
```

Of course, I can do a ForEach loop; it would take care of it easily, but I would like to achieve this in this single line of code.

Any idea ?

Cheers,
Philippe

Comment: why the single line of code requirement? [*frown*] a foreach loop is often far faster than anything that uses the pipeline.

Comment: Saving code length to add clarity for further maintenance (on this example, in real life, where I have no performance issues, I save overall 1 full page of code)

Comment: thanks for the rationale. [*grin*] it's _wrong_, but that is OK. take a look at the code posted by mklement0 for a thorough refutation of "too long". as for maintainability ... laying the steps out clearly is _FAR_ more maintainable than a more-than-simple pipeline. ///// still, as my papa said "if we were all the same, the world would be _boring_ as heck!" [*grin*]

Answer (score 5):

[Mathias R. Jessen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53269899/45375) directly solves your problem, by creating a *script* property (type `ScriptProperty`) that *dynamically* calculates its value from the enclosing object's `.TimeStamp` property.

- The advantage of this approach is that even later changes to `.TimeStamp` will correctly be reflected in `.Time2`, albeit at the cost of having to calculate the value on every access.

[Manuel Batsching's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53270103/45375) answer offers a `Select-Object`-based alternative that creates *static* note properties (type `NoteProperty`), as you've originally attempted yourself.

- The advantage of this approach is that you incur the cost of calculation only once, but later changes to `.TimeStamp` won't be reflected in `.Time2`.

---

To offer **faster PSv5+ alternatives** (a single method call each, spread across multiple lines for readability):

```
# ScriptProperty - dynamic
$TestArray.ForEach({ 
  $_.psobject.properties.Add(
    [psscriptproperty]::new('Time2', { [math]::Round($this.TimeStamp) })
  ) 
})
```

```
# NoteProperty - static
$TestArray.ForEach({ 
  $_.psobject.properties.Add(
    [psnoteproperty]::new('Time2', [math]::Round($_.TimeStamp))
  ) 
})
```

The above solutions use the PSv4+ `.ForEach()` collection method and the PSv5+ static `::new()` type method for calling constructors.

---

Finally, **re one-liner**:

The following `foreach`-loop based note-property solution would have solved your problem too, and would have been *faster*; while it is spread across multiple lines for readability here, it also works as a one-liner:

```
foreach ($el in $TestArray) { 
  Add-Member -InputObject $el -Name Time2 -MemberType NoteProperty `
             -Value ([math]::Round($el.TimeStamp)) 
}
```

Generally, while the pipeline often enables more elegant, single-command solution, that - unfortunately - comes at the expense of performance.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can achieve the same with `Select-Object` and a custom property:

```
$TestArray | Select-Object *,@{ n='Time2';e={ [math]::Round($_.TimeStamp) }}
```

Comment: Very clear and useful comments Manuel. I'll finally go with your last alternative, because I need to do further comparaisons and maths on my TimeStamp value - therefore it is preferable to have it as static NoteProperty type.

Answer (score 1):

Change the member type to `ScriptProperty` and refer to the individual array item as `$this`:

```
$TestArray |Add-Member Time2 -Value { [math]::Round($this.Timestamp) } -MemberType ScriptProperty
```

---

Worth noting that in this example, the pipeline itself acts as a `foreach` loop, unravelling the array and binding each individual item to `Add-Member`

Comment: I had tried with $this but without changing the -MemberType to ScriptProperty !